# Parameterizing max value of a jQuery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create this slider

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemax

Is it possible to parametrize the max value?

For ex:

```
$("#slider-range-max").slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 1,
            max: maxValue,
            value: 2,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
```

Is it possible to pass `maxValue` value, when I click on something? After its been initialized? Not on document ready function, but even after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the values at any time, for `max` you'd do this:

```
$("#slider-range-max").slider("option", "max", newValue);
```

You can see how to do this with all the options [at the jQuery UI site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-max).  Here's an example:

```
$(".increaseMax").click(function() {
  var currentMax = $("#slider-range-max").slider("option", "max");
  $("#slider-range-max").slider("option", "max", currentMax + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the page you gave in your question (click on `Options` and then `max`):

```
Get or set the max option, after init. 
  //getter
  var max = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "max" );
  //setter
  $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "max", 7 );
```

Change `7` to any value/variable you want to set the new maximum value to.